# Why is 2 a pseudoreal representation and there is no 2-2-2 anomaly?

Tags: gauge-theory, group-theory, representation-theory, quantum-anomalies

In [Srednicki's textbook "Quantum Field Theory"](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/qft.html), Problem 89.3 asks us to show that the Standard Model is anomaly free. The answer is given in the [solutions manual](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0xb4crOvCgTM2x6QkhKREg0WW8/edit). On page 150 of the [solutions manual](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0xb4crOvCgTM2x6QkhKREg0WW8/edit), it is stated

> ... There is no $2$-$2$-$2$ anomaly because the $2$ is a pseudoreal representation. ...

where each of the numbers $2$-$2$-$2$ denotes the representation one of the external fields in the triangle diagram that generates the chiral anomaly transforms in. The $2$ denotes the fundamental representation $\mathbf{2}$ of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$, i.e. that with spin-$1/2$. Why is the $2$ a pseudoreal representation? And why is there no $2$-$2$-$2$ anomaly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since isomorphism classes of irreducible representations of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ are classified fully by their half-integer spin $j\in\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}$, there is precisely one irreducible representation of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ of dimension $2j+1$ for each $j$. Therefore, all representations of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ are pseudoreal, i.e. isomorphic to their conjugate representation, since the conjugate representation has the same dimension.

The anomaly cancels for pseudoreal fermions because the anomaly term for contains a factor 
$$A^{abc} = \mathrm{Tr}_R(T^a\{T^b,T^c\})$$
that vanishes in a pseudoreal representation (the $T^a$ are the generators of $\mathrm{SU}(N)$ and the curly brackets are the anti-commutator) because $\mathrm{Tr}_\bar{R}(T^a\{T^b,T^c\}) = -\mathrm{Tr}_R(T^a\{T^b,T^c\}$ for every representation $R$ and its conjugate $\bar{R}$.